# Customize HTML Output of Django ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to add multiple inline form items to a page using Djangos ModelForms. I need Select boxes bound to database models. The forms are formatted and placed in a tabular format so I need to display only the ModelForm without ANY surrounding HTML.

```
class LeagueForm(ModelForm):
league = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=League.objects.all(), empty_label='Manual Team Entry:', required=False)

class Meta:
    model = League
    exclude = ['league_name']
```

Template:

```
{% if selected_sport == 1 %}        
<td>{{ nhl_form.as_p }}</td>
{% else %}
```

The problem is I dont want the paragraph tags, nor tables tags or anything at all. I need to have the form nicely sit where I place it without garbling up the surrounding html.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction? Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just refer to each field separately.

```
{{ nhl_form.league }}
```

will only show the `league` field, with no surrounding cruft.

Comment: And how can I add extra custom CSS class names to each field (for processing with CSS/jQuery later on)?

Comment: @Mark: Details here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields

Comment: @viet, that documentation was very helpful as I did not want to refer to each field separately.

Answer (score 0):

see also http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types-or-widgets